# SQL server - How to prevent customer record being deleted if an order exists for that customer

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a Microsoft access file that links to a SQL server database. At the moment, a user can right click a customer record on a datasheet and select delete record. They need to be able to do this to remove old customers that we no longer need.

However, some customers have orders outstanding and so must not be deleted. What needs to be done on the SQL server side to ensure a customer who has orders in the orders table cannot be deleted from the customers table?

thanks

Comment: Why on earth was this question downvoted??? Stackoverflow should force the downvoter to leave a comment. grrr!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreign key is what you want to create. The master would be your Customer table and the child (detail) would be your Orders table. Once this is in place, no customer row could be deleted if any order rows exist. At least by default it would work this way. You could set up your foreign key to automatically delete child rows when the master is deleted via cascading deletes, but it doesn't sound like this is what you want to do.

You can learn more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx)